# WPF App crash: faulting module mscorwks.dll

Tags: wpf, mscorwks.dll

On some computers that have Win XP SP3 with .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed, my WPF application sometimes crashes. In the Application logs I found these two errors:

1. Faulting application mdp.serve.exe, version 2.1.215.0, stamp 4e302d6a, faulting module mscorwks.dll, version 2.0.50727.3623, stamp 4d8c187e, debug? 0, fault address 0x000a20c1.
   For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
2. .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3623 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A0BC58E) (80131506)
   For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You should look this Microsoft KB :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913384/en-us

This may solve your problem.